# How to hardcode appending to an array on a PHP file using a script?

Tags: php

For example, a PHP file contains this:

```
<?php

return [
    'sample_array' => [
        'sample_index' => 'sample_data',
    ],
];
```

I would like to append values to `sample_array` using a PHP script. What would be the best way to do this?

Edit:
After running the script, file should be updated to:

```
<?php

return [
    'sample_array' => [
        'sample_index' => 'sample_data',
        'sample_index2' => 'sample_data2',
    ],
];
```

Edit:
What I'm looking for is the creation of a script that will directly update the contents of the PHP file to append the array.

Comment: If you just want add value (with a new key) just $sample_array['sample_index2'] = 'sample data2'

Comment: You want to fetch the contents of the PHP-file? What exactly what you mean by the contents of the PHP-file? All the code?

Comment: The file resides locally. What I would like to do is run a script that will update the contents of the file. What I mean by "update the contents of the file" is that the `sample_array` should be appended with additional data (which would be hardcoded in the script) after running the script.

Comment: You want to fetch the array from file1(php) and add som data to that array in file2(php) you mean?

Comment: Do you want to update file1 from file2 with the new extended array?

Comment: There is no file2. I've made edits to the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create valid PHP code through the use of [`var_export()`](http://php.net/var-export). You can then store the code in a file with something like [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file-put-contents).

```
// load the array from the file
$arr = include 'file.php';

// modify the array
$arr['sample_array']['sample_index2'] = 'sample data 2';

// write it back to the file
file_put_contents("file.php", "return " . var_export($arr, true) . ";");
```

gives you...

```
return array (
  'sample_array' =>
  array (
    'sample_index' => 'sample_data',
    'sample_index2' => 'sample data 2',
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: May be worth adding the `<?php` to the start of the file generated.

Comment: @Pardo - I'm glad you got your answer, but wouldn't this be in a second file then? (file2) I'm just curious, I had a hard trying to understand what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi @bestprogrammerintheworld, sorry if I didn't make it more understandable. The script given by @Sherif would update the file (`file.php`) directly after execution. There is no creation of another file.

Comment: Aha @Pardo - no problem. Som misunderstanding in communication only. As I said. I'm glad you got help. That's the important thing!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after array_push

```
<?php
$sample_array = [
  'sample_index' => 'sample_data',
];

array_push($sample_array, array(
  'sample_index2' => 'sample_data2',
));

return $sample_array;
```

With array push, the second argument could be another array that you have already defined with multiple values and keys

More info at [php.net array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: It's possible it might be better then to store it as JSON instead, as PHP and JS can both encode and parse your content into a JSON array and write it to a file